# Searching a word/group of words from a list of files in unix

Tags: unix, grep, find

I want to search the occurrence of a word in all the files from a given folder and view only list of files .I have tried :-
`find . -type f -exec grep -l <keyword> {} \;`
but i am getting the entire line of all the occurrences of the keyword. It s getting kind of messy.

I also tried `grep -hr  <"keyword"> .` but this on is giving :grep: illegal option -- r.

Kindly help.

Comment: are you really including the `<` and `>` chars in your command? That will screw things up. Either use a literal string like `oneWord` or `"two words"` or variables , i.e. `"$1"`, or `"$myVar"`. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter:- No shellter .. It is for explanation purpose. I am using `oneword`

Comment: I think you're doing it right, not obvious where your problem is. For starters, I would confirm that `/bin/grep -l 'knownTextInFile' /path/to/one/fileWithKnownText` text works as expected. If that works, but above still causes problem, then `find . -type f | xargs grep -l 'oneWord'` has worked many times in the past for me. Assuming your OS has xargs. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is up with your `grep`, but this works fine:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -l the {} \;
./br.csv
./combined.csv
./skyscan.csv
./skyscan.db
./team.sql
./uniq.js
```

Maybe check which `grep` you are running.